# Credit union holding car note, refuses to provide details of how payments have been applied

Tags: united-states, texas, banking, loan

A credit union financed a car note for me.  I never knew them before the loan transaction and I only have the car note there.  Recently, my payments seem to not lower my loan balance as much as it should, meaning they are charging me for something I cannot see.  I asked for online access to my history so I could check it.  They said I had to open a depository account in order to have that feature.  How can I concisely ask for my history so that I can figure out what is going on?  Can they refuse to provide that?

Comment: What jurisdiction is this in? What country, and if a federal country such as the US or Canada, what state or province? The laws on what a bank or CU must provide vary.

Comment: It is in Texas.  The CU is Velocity CU out of Austin.

Comment: This is currently an [XY problem](//www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). You've asked them for online access, which isn't what you actually want, just the way you'd *like* to solve your actual problem: determine why your loan balance isn't going down as much as you expected and verify payments are being applied properly. You could also do this by seeing your account history in almost any other manner. There are also many other ways to solve this. Politely ask them how to solve your actual problem, or ask directly for your account history in whatever form they have available.

Comment: @Makyen Why isn't that an answer?

Comment: @CGCampbell Because it doesn't address the issue from the point of view of the law, which is the focus of this site.

Answer (score 5):

They are probably not required to provide online access at all. They are probably required to provide some sort of written statement, unless you have waived that in favor of online or electronic versions. The exact requirements will vary in different jurisdictions.